# Android dicrepancy between /proc/meminfo and StatFs

Tags: android

I am using StatFs to compute memory:

```
totalMem = statFs.getBlockCountLong() * statFs.getBlockSizeLong() / (1024 * 1024);
availMem = statFs.getAvailableBlocks() * statFs.getBlockSizeLong() / (1024 * 1024);
```

When run, this reports:

Total memory = 629
Available memory = 181

However /proc/meminfo reports:

Total memory = 927216K (that is, 905.484M)
Available memory = 75660K (that is, 73.89M)

Shouldn't they report similar results?